# Can a planet move itself?

Tags: planets, physics, orbital-mechanics, stars

Most questions in this vein seem to center around the inhabitants of a planet moving it.  I have a significantly different spin on this idea, though.

So, you're a big ball of rock spinning around a star.  It's nice.  You're getting a nice tan, you don't really think that much because you may have the intelligence of a small animal.  Besides, what thinking you do is really slow.  Very, very slow.  Whatever you use for nerve-type action aren't going to get signals around too quickly.

After a while, you start to feel some kind of prickling on your skin.  A human might say, "Do I have a rash?"  It seems the microscopic (to you) organisms living on your skin are doing quite destructive things to your skin.  You might not even be consciously aware of it.  All your body knows is there's an irritant, and it needs to get off.

Unfortunately, you're a big ball of rock.  No thumbs, or even hands.  There is a big ball of fire that gives you a nice warm glow on the side facing it, though. Maybe that would help burn this rash off.

How do you get there, though?  How does a planet move itself through space.  I'm looking for actual physics answers here.  The best I could come up with is shifting around the center of mass of the planet to (gradually) change its orbit.  I wasn't sure how quickly this could work, though.  I'm sure it would be really slow (geologic time) by human standards, but I'm sure planets have different perceptions of time.

So, the question is, I'm a big ball of rock with a molten core orbiting a star.  Earth is a good frame of reference.  How do I move closer to the star, even if just for a little bit, to burn this rash off my skin?

Comment: Nothing the planet does without expelling mass can change its orbit.  Full stop.

Comment: (Acquiring mass would also work, but that's generally not at the planet's discretion.)

Comment: Looks like most answers point to easier means to get rid of the surface creatures - do you care more about that or about moving the planet? If mobility is what's important here, consider editing the question to provide several motivations or just state that that's the focus.

Comment: You could always add mass by gently bombarding the planet with asteroids. If you want to be nice, they could be sent somewhere remote and relatively uninhabited by the planet's fauna and flora.

Comment: @jdunlop. Planet could open a solar sail or so. That would change the forces applied to it without ejecting or acquiring mass.

Comment: @jdunlop that is just not true. The moon is getting further away from earth as we speak. Real planets are not point particles, and tidal forces can change their orbits.

Comment: What are your rules for what the planet can actively do ("no thumbs, or even hands"), and what just happens to it by the normal rules of physics? Can it create volcanos? Change its plate tectonics? Its magnetic field? Can it expel its atmosphere? Can it split in half? Or is like, actually the planet is just a (non-sentient) planet doing whatever planets do, but an observer might look at what's happening and decide to anthropomorphise what's happening as if it was actively trying to rid itself of life forms etc?

Comment: In real life, planets don't have brains or muscles, so they're not capable of taking any kind of voluntary actions at all. So, in order for your question to have an answer other than the obvious "no, planets can't do anything," your universe has to be different somehow in order to make it so that planets *can* do something. What sort of differences did you have in mind? Are you asking us to make up our own ideas of how your world is different, or do you want to tell us?

Comment: You might enjoy the book "When the World Screamed" by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_the_World_Screamed

Answer (score 18):

*If Mohammed will not go to the mountain, the mountain must come to Mohammed.*

Your idea of getting hotter is good, the critters are sensitive to small temperature variation, but you don't need to get close to the star to get rid of them.

See, the atmosphere you have around your rocky body keeps you warm in the cold of space. Just play with it and cool down a bit. You need to control your volcanoes to give out a lots of gases and ashes, and that will do the trick.

You probably don't remember, but when you were young you [did it already](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deccan_Traps):

> The release of volcanic gases, particularly sulfur dioxide, during the formation of the traps may have contributed to climate change. Data points to an average drop in temperature of about 2 °C (3.6 °F) in this period.
>
> Because of its magnitude, scientists have speculated that the gases released during the formation of the Deccan Traps played a major role in the Cretaceous–Paleogene (K–Pg) extinction event (also known as the Cretaceous–Tertiary or K–T extinction). It has been theorized that sudden cooling due to sulfurous volcanic gases released by the formation of the traps and toxic gas emissions may have contributed significantly to the K–Pg, as well as other, mass extinctions. However, the current consensus among the scientific community is that the extinction was primarily triggered by the Chicxulub impact event in North America, which would have produced a sunlight-blocking dust cloud that killed much of the plant life and reduced global temperature (this cooling is called an impact winter)

In that case you were helped by that smart guy who threw a ball at you, but if you play hard enough with just your volcanoes you can do it again.

As a bonus, you will not lose any mass.

Answer (score 9):

So you're a rocky planet with a molten core & you want to move?

OK then, you just need a big enough volcano & off you go, any big enough volcano will do.

You need to time eruptions to your rotation (if you have any) to avoid going in the wrong direction.

You may experience some weight loss.

> Or rather (for those who don't understand irony when they see it) you
> 'will' experience some weight loss, that's a lot of magma & gas you're
> spewing into space.
>
> That's unavoidable, unless someone else gives you a nudge there's no other way to move in space accept to
> apply the equal & opposite action rule by throwing stuff away from you.
>
> And that means shedding mass whatever drive you use, the only stuff you have is you.

Of course, there are other much easier ways to change your surface temperature that don't involve any weight loss .. just spew gasses out of your volcanos less energetically (so you don't space any mass) & you'll thicken the atmosphere global warming style, or pump large amounts of ash into the atmosphere to shade the surface & you can have an ice age to kill them off.

I'd love to know how your planet manipulates the processes needed to do any of this though

Comment: I'm making the assumption that the planet has some kind of (even if involuntary) control over how material flows inside the core, and possibly how tectonic plates move around on the surface.

Comment: This would be a better answer if it discussed the scale of eruption needed to use it as a rocket. How big is "big enough"?

Comment: @ArcanistLupus The OP hasn't specified neither a mass for his planet or a speed for its movement so that's not possible to calculate isn't it // he asked in general terms so can't expect (or get) an answer in anything other than general terms.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus The OP hasn't specified neither a mass for his planet or a speed for its movement so that's not possible to calculate isn't it // you are essentially demanding the impossible // he asked in general terms so can't expect (or get) an answer in anything other than general terms.

Comment: @Pelinore I didn't mean a hard number calculation, more like a [Fermi estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem).  Does a "big volcano" mean Olympus Mons, or something that's several thousand times bigger?  It makes a difference in how your worldbuilding goes, and the calculation should be possible with 'Earth-like' as the only planet parameters.

Comment: Unless your super volcano is actually spewing stuff out of the atmosphere you don't have a net force, and thus no propulsion.

Comment: :@D.J.Klomp well duh! // of course // I thought that was obvious to anyone (accept perhaps believers in perpetual motion, & there's not much point catering for them) // I'm sorry, excuse me for assuming more education in our readers than you think they have, my mistake, I'll edit a line to that effect in later.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus K2 is probably getting close to as high a peak as you can get on earth, eventually you reach a height where the weight of the rock above will cause the rock below to flow like putty so that the peak sinks, so there's a limit on how big in terms of height a volcano can be, the escape velocity of Earth is 11.19 km/s, volcanoes throw rocks at velocities of 200-300 m/sec when they  erupt explosively, so it's not actually possible with an earth sized planet,, it actually has to be a lot smaller than the moon I think..

Comment: :@ArcanistLupus *"has to be a lot smaller than the moon I think"* but then again the smaller the planet the higher the peak can be so the less power needed to eject stuff into space from the peak so maybe it could be done with a planet bigger than that, bit that's a whole lot of math & stuff I don't want to try & calculate.

Answer (score 6):

"shifting around the center of mass of the planet to (gradually) change its orbit" will not work. At all.

Maybe if you flex your magnetic field muscles you could interact with the Sun, or another planet's magnetic field.

But if you really want to get rid of the icky stuff on your surface, just recycle the surface! a Teensy bit of vulcanism will clear that infection right off! And as a bonus, you soon form new, shiny basalt fields to erase even the last little tracks of the bugs from your skin.

Comment: Or you could eject ferromagnetic material into space at high velocity through some kind of specialized magnetic volcano, where the convection currents of the magma are charged and generating fields, or sequences of fields.

Comment: @luke unless you manage to get the stuff to escape velocity, *after* its been slowed down by ploughing through the atmosphere, it will just fall back and result is zero net thrust. The mind boggles at just what a "magnetic volcano" would look like that is capable of the needed 14-18km/s of ejection speed.

Comment: Yes, obviously it would require escape velocity and sufficient energy to keep it after passing through the atmosphere. These are both factors that would be easier to overcome on Mars than Earth, for instance, and would vary from planet to planet. It would look like a naturally occurring railgun, whose electromagnetic fields are created by rotating charged material.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple ways a planet could move without building itself a big reaction drive (rocket).  How effective they are, though, depends on unspecified details of the planet and solar system.

(1) The [Yarkovsky Effect](https://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/the-yarkovsky-effect-pushing-asteroids-around-with-sunlight) is an interaction between sunlight and the planet's rotation which produces net thrust. (And here's [what Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarkovsky_effect).) Basically, the day side of a planet is hotter than the night side and emits more IR which produces a small but very real thrust directly away from the sun. If a planet poles point away from its orbital plane, rotation displaces the hot side in the direction of rotation and the thrust from the extra IR will now speed up or slow down the planet and change its orbit.

The Yarkovsky Effect is most important for smaller bodies being directly related to surface area, rotation speed and inversely related to mass. But for mid-sized asteroids it is a huge effect which we must take into account in our own Solar System. (It would be a very slow process for an Earth-sized planet.)

A planetary being should be able to simulate the YE by moving its atmosphere around or changing its rock color thus shifting the center of temperature away from the sub-solar point or by changing atmospheric reflectivity/emissivity.  The key point is to keep the hottest point off center from the dayside.

This would be a slow process, but, hey, planets are long-lived.

(2) Speaking of long-lived, there's also the Interplanetary Transport Network

(It really exists!) The [Interplanetary Transport Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_Transport_Network) is a subtle phenomenon produced by the combined gravitational fields of the planets. It's a continually changing set of trajectories which link Lagrangian points together and where an object -- any object of any mass -- can move about with very minor expenditures of energy.

(There's no violation of conservation of energy -- the energy is stolen from the other planetary bodes via small-scale [gravity assists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist).)

The only real gotcha is that if the body being moved is large, its own mass affects the ITN's pathways, but this can certainly be taken into account.  (For *us* there's a second gotcha -- the ITN is *slow*, making it impractical for many uses.  But for a planet? No prob.)

Combining #1 and #2, I see no reason why a living planet with an atmosphere in a solar system with other planets present couldn't move itself wherever it wanted to given enough time.

Answer (score 4):

You're correct. You can shift mass around the center of mass in order to move that center of mass over time. It's called [Tidal acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_acceleration). The natural tides, caused by the Moon, due to Earth's rotation, are ahead of the Moon and therefore gravitationally drag the Moon, pushing it away from the Earth at an amazingly high speed of 3.78 cm/year. The relevance of this effect in relation to the Sun is doubtful: while the Sun's gravitational pull on Earth is quite strong due to its mass, the tidal force is much weaker than that of the Moon (because distance is more relevant, it's squared for gravitational force but cubed for tidal force), and likewise the torque of the tide bulge on the Sun must be much weaker.

If you're willing to give your planet the ability to shift its mass, then it can create non-tidal bulges, perhaps much higher and denser (rock instead of water). But the effectiveness of this approach would never get close to some other answers here, unless you'd be willing to go to the extremes - but then you can as well extend a very long rocky arm to grab the Sun and pull itself closer.

Comment: Fun fact, Earth itself has tidal bulges, but its oceans do not: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/121858/168452

Answer (score 3):

### They can and DO.  At least, Galilean moons of Jupiter are believed to.

See [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02825) (which was published after peer review, but behind a paywall).  See section 3.4 - the moons of Jupiter are heated by tides in their subsurface oceans, *when they are in resonance*, and this changes the semimajor axis.

What I take this to mean is that in theory you could introduce a few milligrams of terrestrial microorganisms into the seas of Europa, make the viscosity of the water change, watch the tidal movement of the ocean drag the moon inward or outward, and have it smash into another of Jupiter's moons, sending out shrapnel in many directions capable of destroying life on Earth ... all by pure biology!  It might take some planning (not to mention time) and it might be a very "optimistic" interpretation of the rather hard to fathom content of the PDF, but it seems plausible enough for good sci fi.